# Can I downscale from 600dpi to 300dpi for Adobe's ClearScan without running OCR again?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, clearscan

Practically changing dpi would be done by selecting the original scan and `Recognize Text using OCR` 
and then select the `300dpi`

[image]

But I already have a 600dpi ClearScan OCRed document and I want to avoid the long process of running the OCR
again.

Can I downscale from 600dpi CelarScan to 300dpi ClearScan using Adobe Acrobat without running OCR again?

Answer (score 1):

Once a document has passed OCR, it can not run through OCR again in Acrobat (that's an Acrobat limitation).

So, your options would be either start again from the original scans (preferrable), or export as TIFF and run OCR again (second choice, because there would be a second downsampling of the images).